# strange result about rownum in the oracle sql

Tags: sql, join, rownum

this is a table called nums.

```
| id |
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
```

I execute the SQL:

```
with s as (
 select id, rownum rn from nums
)

select s1.id id1,s1.rn rn1, s2.id id2, s2.rn rn2 
from s s1 join s s2 
on s1.id != s2.id
```

the result is :

```
|id1|rn1|id2|rn2|
|1  |1  |2  |2  |
|1  |1  |3  |3  |
|2  |4  |1  |1  |
|2  |4  |3  |3  |
|3  |4  |1  |1  |
|3  |4  |2  |2  |
```

why there is the num 4 in the result?

Comment: which version  are you using, is it fully patched, because it works as intended see https://dbfiddle.uk/zEa2qCwW

Comment: Personal Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: it doesn't show your problem as you see n the fiddle

Comment: maybe because of oracle version

Comment: the fiddle wit oracle 11 has the sem version number as yours, if it consists report it to the bugtracker

Comment: It does show the same problem in [an 11g fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-2y8iIsR). It doesn't in [21c](https://dbfiddle.uk/ol28PCPH). So it's a bug that's been fixed at some point, probably long ago in a patch.